# Is there an easy way to customize try-except error code outputs in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I am trying to custimize my error codes in a script that I am writing and I was wondering if I can adjust the output. Here is the scenario. Running this script:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = "Hello World"
        int(x)
    except (ValueError, RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, SystemExit):

        sys.exit("Error: Check Section 1.0")
```

Creates an output of:

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
SystemExit: Error: Check Section 1.0
```

Is there an easy way, when an error occurs, the script stops and only says:

```
Error: Check Section 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `print` and do `break` since you keep it inside a loop

```
while True:
    try:
        x = "Hello World"
        int(x)
    except:
        print("Error: Check Section 1.0")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, this method direct shows you "Error: Check Section 1.0" only.

```
while True:
    try:
       x = "Hello World"
       int(x)
    except:
       sys.exit("Error: Check Section 1.0")
```

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue on my side: "An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. {/n} SystemExit: Error: Check Section 1.0"